# How to preprocess/convert data of a databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, bezier

I am creating a `DataGrid` that is going to define (through user-input) the X and Y values of a curve which will be presented on the same window. The curve is going to be defined by a `Path` containing a series of `QuadraticBezierCurve` objects.

However, while the user will input the coordinates of the points that the path will go *through*, a `QuadraticBezierCurve`'s data contains information regarding its endpoints and a control point, which is **not** a point it will go through (other than in a straight line). I've already done the math to figure out how to calculate the control point as defined by the three coordinates the curve must go through, but now I need to create this curve.

Is it possible to bind the `DataGrid` to a "buffer" dataset which is processesed (though code-behind) and this result is bound to the `QuadraticBezierCurve`?

Or will I need to, on user input, delete the existing path and construct a new one?

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: I unfortunately haven't been able to work on this these last few days. And I'm a beginner to MVVM and WPF, so I'm having to study a bit to even understand your answer. >.> I've always shied away from meta-data and reflection in my previous projects, but I see it is pretty much essencial to how MVVM and WPF function, so I'm finally having to sit down and figure this stuff out. But thanks for the concern. Hopefully over the weekend I'll be able to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

By virtue of binding `ItemsSource` to a collection, each row of your `DataGrid` will be bound to an item in that collection. Assuming MVVM, each item will be a view model. That view model can have properties for the values the user enters, and any changes can cause a recalculation in another that exposes the control point. Another part of your UI can be bound to that same property, so will automatically refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As Kent says, in a MVVM approach you could define a ViewModel with two collections, one for the user input data and one which exposes the converted items which the path can be bound to. Then you need to define, when the collection for the path needs to get refreshed. This means manually subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event of the collection with the user input coordinates (only if the user can add or remove points) and to the `PropertyChanged` event of each user coordinate (in any case). Whether this is required, depends on whether you want to allow the user to change coordinates that are already in the list.

**Coordinates don't change after they have been added to the list**

If not, there is a much more straightforward way, using a ValueConverter. As what you are trying to achieve then, is a straight-forward conversion, I would suggest using the built-in WPF mechanisms for conversion. These work for a MVVM and a non-MVVM approach alike.

Define a converter to transform a coordinate as you have it stored in each item of the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` to the path segment. This contains the math you've already figured out and not much more:

```
public class CoordinateToPathSegment : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var coordinate = value as CurveViewModel.Coordinate;
        var segment = new QuadraticBezierSegment();

        // Set properties of quadratic bezier element

        return segment;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You expose an instance of this converter in your app's/window's/control's resources. For general info on converters have alook here: [WPFTutorial: Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html).

Then wire it all together with something like this:

```
 <Path Data="{Binding ItemsSource, 
                      ElementName=CoordinateGrid, 
                      Mode=OneWay, 
                      Converter={StaticResource CoordinateToSegmentConverter}}" />
```

This way your path is always in synch with the datagrid and the user input coordinates get converted to path segments automatically without you needing to care about the refreshing yourself. Again: Note that changes of an already existing UserCoordinate won't be forwarded to the UI, as once a coordinate has been converted to a `PathSegment`, there is no reference between the two anymore. The path will only get refreshed when Coordinates are added/deleted in the DataGrid.

**Coordinates can be changed by the user after they have been added to the list**

If you want to allow the user to change single values of already defined coordinates, there's a bit more to it. Then you need to got the way that Kent proposed. The principle looks about like this:

```
public class CurveViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Collection<PathSegment> _segments;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Coordinate> _userInputCoordinates;

    public ObservableCollection<Coordinate> UserInputCoordinates
    {
        get { return _userInputCoordinates; }
    }

    public Collection<PathSegment> Segments
    {
        get { return _segments; }
        private set
        {
            _segments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Segments);
        }
    }

    public CurveViewModel()
    {
        _userInputCoordinates = new ObservableCollection<Coordinate>();

        // Subscribe to refresh the path on adding/deleting ne coordinates
        UserInputCoordinates.CollectionChanged += UserInputCoordinates_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void UserInputCoordinates_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                var newItems = args.NewItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
                foreach (var coordinate in newItems)
                {
                    // Subscribe to property change of a particular coordinate to refresh the 
                    // curve when user changes the values of an already existing coordinate data set
                    coordinate.PropertyChanged += Coordinate_PropertyChanged;
                }
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                var oldItems = args.OldItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
                foreach (var coordinate in oldItems)
                {
                    // Unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
                    coordinate.PropertyChanged -= Coordinate_PropertyChanged;
                }
                break;
        }

        // This refreshes the path when a coordinate has been added/removed
        RefreshPath();
    }

    private void Coordinate_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshPath();
    }

    private void RefreshPath()
    {
        var segments = new Collection<PathSegment>();

        foreach (var userInputCoordinate in UserInputCoordinates)
        {
            var segment = new QuadraticBezierSegment();
            // Set properties here
            segments.Add(segment);
        }

        Segments = segments;
    }

    public class Coordinate : ViewModelBase
    {
        private double _xStart;

        public double XStart
        {
            get { return _xStart; }
            set
            {
                _xStart = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("XStart");
            }
        }

        // Analogous properties for YStart, XEnd, YEnd, XControl, YControl
    }
}
```

Then you bind `Data` of the path to `Segments`. I hope the comments explain more or less how it works.

Let me knwo if this answers your question and solves the problem.